# How can I get Google AdSense to approve my Web App?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have developed a webpage and applied for AdSense and they disapproved for the following reason:

> Site does not comply with Google policies: We're unable to approve your AdSense application at this time because your site does not comply with the Google AdSense program policies or adhere to the Webmaster Quality guidelines. It's our goal to provide our advertisers sites that offer rich and meaningful content, receive organic traffic, and allow us to serve well-targeted ads to users. We believe that currently your site does not fulfill this criteria.
>
> Here are some recommendations to help you improve the user experience on your site and comply with AdSense criteria:
>
> - It’s important for sites displaying Google ads to offer significant value to the user. As a publisher, you must provide unique and relevant content that gives users a reason to visit your site first.
> - Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
> - Your site should also provide a good user experience through clear navigation and organization. Users should be able to easily click through your pages and find the information they’re seeking.

From my research, I made sure that my website has the following:

- English content
- Included privacy policy
- 6 Months Old
- Included About Us page
- Included Contact Us page
- Original images (except the about page background image)
- No hacking or gambling and adult content
- 100+ pages and daily 50+ user
- Top domain (i.e .com)
- Included Analytics, XML sitemap, *robots.txt*

The content is not just text description but provides a code snippet with a hands on working example.  I've created the site honestly with out editing the code, or copying and pasting from other sites.

How do I find the odds of being approved?  They are replying with the common and related violation info that they send to everybody.

Answer (score 2):

AdSense reviewers rarely look beyond the home page.   Your home page does does not appear to meet the guidelines:

- Your menu only has five pages in it.   Once you click into the "Android" section, there is an additional left hand menu with tons of other pages in it.   It would be helpful to link these pages from your home page during the AdSense review.
- Your home page features a tag cloud which is not clickable.   Tag clouds are usually links to your content.   Your tag cloud appears to a feature list.   You should choose a different home page image during the period of your AdSense review to avoid the appearance of unclear navigation.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the quick reply and pointing the odds. Let me change them and apply again for adsense and get back to you.

Comment: Well they rejected again with the same reason and changed the question to be more specific to other user rather than certain webpage.

Comment: @chiru..did you got google adsense